# benchmark results for VRPTW - comparing jsprit and ortools-vrp solvers?

Tags: or-tools, jsprit, vehicle-routing

I've been trying to find results for some known VRPTW benchmarks (e.g. http://neo.lcc.uma.es/vrp/known-best-results/) for comparing [jsprit](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/blob/master/docs/Meta-Heuristic.md) vs. [ortools-vrp](https://acrogenesis.com/or-tools/documentation/user_manual/manual/vrp/first_vrp_implementation.html#the-basic-program), using the best search-heuristics both have to offer. Is there some known resource for that?

Comment: AFAIK no such comparison is out yet. You'll have to benchmark them yourself. Myself I am interested in or-tools vs Optaplanner, but I couldn't fin anything on it either so I am working on a project where I compare both. Will take some time to finish thoguh on my end.

Comment: did you end up benchmarking?

Comment: @ShubhamJain, not yet :(